# passing value from one domain to nother domain

Tags: javascript, vbscript

want to pass value from one domain to another domain, I was tried to pass it by query string but that value contains large number of characters so didn't get all value by using query string, can you please tell me how can I do that.

Following is the code that passes the value to another domain

```
var iframe='<iframe src="'+url_to_download+'" style="display:none;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="0px" height="0px"></iframe>';
```

Following is the code that reads the passed value from query string

```
<%


orders=request.QueryString("ordered_products")
orders=replace(orders,"-aspx",".aspx")
orders=replace(orders,"_","&")
'urlredirect=request.QueryString("url")
cooki=request.Cookies("products_ordered")
orderid=request.QueryString("orderid")
response.Write("<script>alert('"&orders&"')</script>")







%>
```

Comment: use a form with with a input type hidden, set the target to your iframe and method=post, then use `document.getElementById("your_form").submit()` in js to send the value that you need

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate of many, many posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assemble your data into JSON and use jQuery's JSONP functionality to request the data from domain1 on domain2. http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/